# How to build nested Maven/Quarkus project with Docker?

Tags: docker, maven, quarkus

I can build a Maven/Quarkus project locally with the commands below. However I have been unable to Dockerize the building, so the build wouldn't depend on the local Maven, Java, etc versions. Ultimately I want to put the build process into Jenkins.

#### Build locally

1. Build extensions

   ```
   cd project01/backend
   maven:latest mvn clean install \
       -Dquarkus.container-image.build=true \
       -DskipTests
   ```
2. Build service, this produces a Docker image of admin service. There are multiple services.

   ```
   cd project01/backend/admin
   maven:latest mvn clean install \
       -Dquarkus.container-image.build=true \
       -DskipTests
   ```

#### Build with Docker and Maven image

1. Building extensions go through and should be equivalent to the 1st command without Maven Docker container.

   ```
   cd project01/
   docker run -it --rm --name project01-build \
       -v "$(pwd)":/usr/src/project01 \
       -w /usr/src/project01/backend maven:latest mvn clean install \
       -Dquarkus.native.container-image.build=true \
       -DskipTests
   ```
2. Building service fails

   ```
   cd project01/
   srv="admin"
   docker run -it --rm --name project01-build \
       -v "$(pwd)":/usr/src/project01 \
       -w /usr/src/project01/backend/service/"$srv" maven:latest mvn clean install \
       -Dquarkus.native.container-image.build=true \
       -DskipTests
   ```

Building a service fails with an error. The build process doesn't seem to find the extensions built in the previous step.

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project admin: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.project01:admin:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.project01.extension:locking-extension:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT (absent), com.project01.extension:marshaller-extension:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT (absent), com.project01.extension:metadata-extension:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT (absent), com.project01.extension:model-extension:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT (absent), com.project01.extension:util-extension:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT (absent), com.project01.extension:validation-extension:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT (absent): Could not find artifact com.project01.extension:locking-extension:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT

Without changing the build command from `-Dquarkus.container-image.build=true` to `Dquarkus.native.container-image.build=true` even the 1st build with Docker fails.

Comment: I've realized that creatingimages with Quarkus inside Docker container is not easy, so I changed my approach to run Maven wrapper `./mvnw` commands in the Jenkins pipeline.